# Python: Difference between query in code and query in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

**My Code:**

```
date_today = datetime.date.today()
date_curr_year = date_today.year
date_curr_month = date_today.month
date_curr_month_1d = datetime.date(day=1, month=date_curr_month, year=date_curr_year)
date_prev_month = date_curr_month_1d - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
string_date_prev_month = date_prev_month.strftime("%Y-%m-1")
string_date_curr_month_1d = date_curr_month_1d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

try:
    #Query:
    q_getstuff = "SELECT `timestamp`, `number`, `url`, `procedure` FROM transaction WHERE `number` IS NOT NULL AND (`timestamp` >= \'" + string_date_prev_month + "\' AND `timestamp` < \'" + string_date_curr_month_1d + "\')"
    print q_getstuff

    #Database Connection
    con = mdb.connect(hostname, username, password, database)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(q_getstuff)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    numrows = cur.rowcount

    for row in result:
        print row

except mdb.Error, e:
    print "Error " + str(e.args[0]) + " " + str(e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

con.close()
```

The whole date crap is simply to get the first date of this month, and the first date of the previous month. The query is supposed to get the data from last month. If there's a better way to do this, please let me know.

Here's the result of the `print q_getstuff`:

```
SELECT `timestamp`, `number`, `url`, `procedure` FROM transaction
WHERE `number` IS NOT NULL AND (`timestamp` >= '2015-02-1' AND
`timestamp` < '2015-03-01')
```

Take note that the field names are enclosed in tildes. It seems right, no errors. If I print out `numrows`, it returns 2, as in, *2 rows*.

**The Problem:**

I copy the output of `print q_getstuff`, and just straight up paste it (no edits) into MySQL, and it returns *78 rows*.

So obviously something's wrong with the code, but I'm not sure what's happening. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but restarting everything (database, computer) fixed it.

Guess it wasn't the code after all, and more something to do with MySQL itself.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this:

```
q_getstuff = "SELECT timestamp, number, url, procedure FROM transaction WHERE number IS NOT NULL AND (timestamp >= '%s' AND timestamp < '%s')" % (string_date_prev_month, string_date_curr_month_1d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way of constructing the query seems odd. More standard way would be:

```
q_getstuff = "SELECT timestamp, number, url, procedure FROM transaction WHERE number IS NOT NULL AND (timestamp >= ? AND timestamp < ?)"
cur.execute(q_get_stuff, (string_date_prev_month, string_date_curr_month_1d))
```

Database API will take care of proper quoting and escaping your variables.

Comment: I get a `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` when I did that. But basically, I just did that so I can print it out.

Comment: What type of DB are you connecting to? Question marks are proper place holder when connecting to Sqlite. For other, like MySQL, you would use %s instead. However logic still stands that you should let DB connector do the work of inserting variables into query.

Comment: MySQL, as tagged, though I forgot to mention it in the question itself.